# RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I am currently trying to update my Discord bot from V12 to V13, and I am currently running into a very frustrating problem. So essentially I am creating a kind of an event command where people can react to attend, every time someone reacts the embed edits itself and that where the problem lies. So how I did it V12 is I edited the message via function that would update the values.

```
message.edit({
    embeds: [
        await updateEmbed(
            embedPref,
            users[0],
            users[1],
            users[2],
            displayText[0],
            displayText[1],
            displayText[2],
            displayText[3]
        ),
    ],
});
```

I don't believe this is where the problem originates due to the nature of the error. Here is the code for the updating of the Embeds:

```
function updateEmbed(option, users1, users2, users3, ...displayText) {
const upatedDndEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`**D&D** at ${displayTime}`)
    .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/u0aN19t.png")
    .setDescription(displayText[0])
    .setColor("DC143C")
    .addFields(
        { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
        { name: "Campaign:", value: `${displayText[1]}`, inline: true },
        { name: "DM:", value: `${displayText[2]}`, inline: true },
        { name: "Whereabout:", value: `${displayText[3]}`, inline: true },
        { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
        {
            name: `<:accepted:867150417271324672>Accepted (${users1.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users1.length !== 0 ? users1 : "-",
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: `<:unsure:867150452423131166>Unsure (${users2.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users2.length !== 0 ? users2 : "-",
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: `<:denied:867150431612436510>Denied (${users3.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users3.length !== 0 ? users3 : "-",
            inline: true,
        }
    )
    .setFooter(`This message was issued by ${msgSender}`)
    .setTimestamp(new Date());

console.log("I got here 2 ");

const upatedGameEventEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`**Game Event** at ${displayTime}`)
    .setThumbnail(
        "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/836600699080671262/855459529763323914/The_Chill_Pill.png"
    )
    .setDescription(displayText[0])
    .setColor("DC143C")
    .addFields(
        { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
        { name: "Game:", value: `${displayText[1]}`, inline: true },
        { name: "Additional Notes:", value: `${displayText[2]}`, inline: true },
        { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
        {
            name: `<:accepted:867150417271324672>Accepted (${users1.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users1.length !== 0 ? users1 : "-",
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: `<:unsure:867150452423131166>Unsure (${users2.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users2.length !== 0 ? users2 : "-",
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: `<:denied:867150431612436510>Denied (${users3.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users3.length !== 0 ? users3 : "-",
            inline: true,
        }
    )
    .setFooter(`This message was issued by ${msgSender}`)
    .setTimestamp(new Date());

const upatedEventEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`**Event** at ${displayTime}`)
    .setThumbnail(
        "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/836600699080671262/855459529763323914/The_Chill_Pill.png"
    )
    .setDescription(displayText[0])
    .setColor("DC143C")
    .addFields(
        { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
        { name: "Event:", value: `${displayText[1]}`, inline: true },
        { name: "Additional Notes:", value: `${displayText[2]}`, inline: true },
        { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
        {
            name: `<:accepted:867150417271324672>Accepted (${users1.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users1.length !== 0 ? users1 : "-",
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: `<:unsure:867150452423131166>Unsure (${users2.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users2.length !== 0 ? users2 : "-",
            inline: true,
        },
        {
            name: `<:denied:867150431612436510>Denied (${users3.length}/${memberCount})`,
            value: users3.length !== 0 ? users3 : "-",
            inline: true,
        }
    )
    .setFooter(`This message was issued by ${msgSender}`)
    .setTimestamp(new Date());

return option === 1 ? upatedDndEmbed : option === 2 ? upatedGameEventEmbed : upatedEventEmbed;
```

}

This code worked just fine in V12 but is now returning the error:

> RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be
> non-empty strings.

EDIT: So I found the problem, you can't have arrays as the value of a field anymore apparently. That Explains why this wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#strings needs to be validated through either the method `.toString()` or template literals. Which my code did not. So to fix this I added `.join("\n")` after all user arrays. This essentially splits all the elements in the array with a line break. Fixed code:

```
    function updateEmbed(option, users1, users2, users3, ...displayText) {
        const users1Length = users1.length;
        const users2Length = users2.length;
        const users3Length = users3.length;

        const updatedDndEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**D&D** at ${displayTime}`)
            .setThumbnail("https://i.imgur.com/u0aN19t.png")
            .setDescription(displayText[0])
            .setColor("DC143C")
            .addFields(
                { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
                { name: "Campaign:", value: `${displayText[1]}`, inline: true },
                { name: "DM:", value: `${displayText[2]}`, inline: true },
                { name: "Whereabout:", value: `${displayText[3]}`, inline: true },
                { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
                {
                    name: `<:accepted:867150417271324672>Accepted (${users1Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users1Length !== 0 ? users1.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: `<:unsure:867150452423131166>Unsure (${users2Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users2Length !== 0 ? users2.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: `<:denied:867150431612436510>Denied (${users3Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users3Length !== 0 ? users3.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                }
            )
            .setFooter(`This message was issued by ${msgSender}`)
            .setTimestamp(new Date());

        const updatedGameEventEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**Game Event** at ${displayTime}`)
            .setThumbnail(
                "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/836600699080671262/855459529763323914/The_Chill_Pill.png"
            )
            .setDescription(displayText[0])
            .setColor("DC143C")
            .addFields(
                { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
                { name: "Game:", value: `${displayText[1]}`, inline: true },
                { name: "Additional Notes:", value: `${displayText[2]}`, inline: true },
                { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
                {
                    name: `<:accepted:867150417271324672>Accepted (${users1Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users1Length !== 0 ? users1.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: `<:unsure:867150452423131166>Unsure (${users2Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users2Length !== 0 ? users2.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: `<:denied:867150431612436510>Denied (${users3Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users3Length !== 0 ? users3.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                }
            )
            .setFooter(`This message was issued by ${msgSender}`)
            .setTimestamp(new Date());

        const updatedEventEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**Event** at ${displayTime}`)
            .setThumbnail(
                "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/836600699080671262/855459529763323914/The_Chill_Pill.png"
            )
            .setDescription(displayText[0])
            .setColor("DC143C")
            .addFields(
                { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
                { name: "Event:", value: `${displayText[1]}`, inline: true },
                { name: "Additional Notes:", value: `${displayText[2]}`, inline: true },
                { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" },
                {
                    name: `<:accepted:867150417271324672>Accepted (${users1Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users1Length !== 0 ? users1.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: `<:unsure:867150452423131166>Unsure (${users2Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users2Length !== 0 ? users2.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                },
                {
                    name: `<:denied:867150431612436510>Denied (${users3Length}/${memberCount})`,
                    value: users3Length !== 0 ? users3.join("\n") : "-",
                    inline: true,
                }
            )
            .setFooter(`This message was issued by ${msgSender}`)
            .setTimestamp(new Date());

        return option === 1
            ? updatedDndEmbed
            : option === 2
            ? updatedGameEventEmbed
            : updatedEventEmbed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing values you set as

```js
users1.length !== 0 ? users1 : "-"
```

to

```js
users1 || "-"
```

Maybe `users1` is an [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), maybe `users1.length` is returning you [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) or [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) and not exactly `0` so use that to see for yourself, if it still doesn't work, before creating the embed use

```js
console.log([users1,users2,users3,displayText...])
```

To be sure what exactly are those variables.

Comment: So the thing is I already checked this. And when I console.log(users1.length !== 0 ? users1 : "-") and the array is empty it always returnes "-". I am just really confused this totally worked V12

Comment: @KraftaN just do console.log(users1) and tell what do you see